# modin incorrect syntax error on read_sql with oracle

Tags: pandas, oracle, modin

Using modin's implementation of read_sql, I am getting a syntax error. It seems to be due to the aliasing of the count query generated in read_sql.

Am I doing something wrong or is this due to a lack of compatibility with oracle?

Also, note that passing the same arguments to `pandas.read_sql()` does not cause this error.

```
import modin.pandas as pd
query = """select distinct col_a, col_b FROM test_table"""
df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```

> sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

> [SQL: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (select distinct col_a, col_b FROM test_table) AS _]

Comment: The query generator works incorrectly, because Oracle doesn't allow `as` before table alias. This is an old issue mentioned in the thread (looks like you've already reported a bug here): https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues/979